# Handling Collecting Player Data from Multiple Scripts [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save

I have been working on a Save System to save my Players data and that is working fine. However, I'm not sure as to what is the best way to compile all of my Players Data as all of it's attributes (health, etc.) is split into different classes e.g PlayerHealthManager. Right now I'm pretty sure the way I'm doing it is a complete mess and probably wrong in a lot of places.

I have a base Player class which uses a Singleton and basically holds references to all of the components whose data I need e.g the PlayerHealthManager. I then have a PlayerDataManager class who uses the info from the singleton to compile the Player data into a struct and send it to the SaveSystem, however this feels really messy. Code attached below. If anyone knows of a better way to do things or if this is correct help would be much appreciated

```
public class PlayerDataManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static event Action<PlayerData> OnPlayerDataLoaded = delegate { };

    void Start()
    {
        PlayerData data = (PlayerData)SaveSystem.LoadPlayer();
        OnPlayerDataLoaded(data);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        SavePlayerData();
    }

    public PlayerData GetPlayerData()
    {
        if (Player.instance != null)
        {
            var playerData = new PlayerData();
            Player p = Player.instance;

            // Players Health Fields
            playerData.health = p.HealthManager.Health;
            playerData.maxHealth = p.HealthManager.MaxHealth;

            // Player position fields
            playerData.position = new float[2];
            playerData.position[0] = p.transform.position.x;
            playerData.position[1] = p.transform.position.y;

            return playerData;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("No player found");
            return new PlayerData();
        }

    }

    public void SavePlayerData()
    {
        SaveSystem.SavePlayer(GetPlayerData());
    }

}
```

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(PlayerHealthManager))]
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    PlayerHealthManager healthManager;
    public static Player instance = null;

    public PlayerHealthManager HealthManager { get { return healthManager; } }
    void Awake()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        healthManager = GetComponent<PlayerHealthManager>();
        PlayerDataManager.OnPlayerDataLoaded += InitializeData;
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        PlayerDataManager.OnPlayerDataLoaded -= InitializeData;
    }

    void InitializeData(PlayerData data)
    {
        Vector2 newPosition = new Vector2(data.position[0], data.position[1]);
        transform.position = newPosition;

        healthManager.InitializeData(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you saving the data in your SaveSystem?

Comment: @Dave sorry yes I am serializing the data should have mentioned that

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are serializing the data in your `SaveSystem`. Make the classes/fields/attributes serializable (ways to do it are different depending on the serializer you use) so you don't have to clone the data to another object.

Basically you want to get rid of `GetPlayerData` and `PlayerData` and be able to do `SaveSystem.SavePlayer(Player.instance);` Player class already has all the information and you can decide what should be serialized and what not.

If you want to keep the serialazble data in a separate class/struct `PlayerData` add `PlayerData playerdata;` to your Player class and add `PlayerHealthManager` and other fields to the PlayerData class. You could then do `SaveSystem.SavePlayer(Player.instance.playerData);`

In case of binary serialization I can recommend Protocol Buffers. It makes serializing data simple and it is very efficient. You can use [protobuf-net](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) for quick integration.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I need to keep the PlayerData struct as I use it to pass the data around elsewhere but I can see how it would be easier to just get rid of the PlayerDataManager class all together. However I just wasn't sure if the Player class was the right place to do it as the PlayerDataManager also does the loading of the data, which I thought would be weird to do in the Player class which I may need to do other things in the future

Comment: No problem. See no reason why you could not have a Load method in the Player class that would handle loading of the data. You can also handle loading of the data in SaveSystem. Rename it SaveLoadSystem and add a LoadPlayer method.